# Assign datatable column to chart column color

Tags: sql, asp.net, stored-procedures, charts, datatable

I am using *ASP.NET* chart to show results from a *SQL* Stored Procedure and I am using the very last stored proc column as a colorID to show which color I would like each column in the the graph to be. The stored proc has 6 columns and 6 rows as seen below(I used example numbers below). The colorID range is either 0,1,2.

The issue is that the chart column colors are not dynamically changing to what the records are showing in the stored proc. The code below is just taking the very last record `ColorID` number and using that for every bar color.

I have searched many examples online but no luck and this is my first post so forgive any uploading mistakes. Any help on this would be appreciated.Thank you.

```
col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | ColorID
-----+------+------+------+------+--------
     |      |      |      |      |    0
     |      |      |      |      |    1
     |      |      |      |      |    2
     |      |      |      |      |    0
     |      |      |      |      |    0
     |      |      |      |      |    0
```

Here is the code below :

```
For Each dataRow As DataRow In ds.Rows
    For Each dataColumn As DataColumn In ds.Columns
        For Each pt As Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.DataPoint In Chart1.Series("Series1").Points
            If (dataRow("ColorID").ToString() = "0") Then
                pt.Color = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ff4000")
            ElseIf (dataRow("ColorID").ToString() = "1") Then
                pt.Color = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#e6e600")
            ElseIf (dataRow("ColorID").ToString() = "2") Then
                pt.Color = Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#009933")
            End If
        Next
    Next
Next
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure this out using a different method shown below.

```
            Dim array As String()
            Dim labelsList As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
            For Each row As DataRow In ds.Rows
                labelsList.Add(row.Item("ColorID"))
            Next

            aar = labelsList.ToArray()

            '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
            If aar(0) = "0" Then
                Chart1.Series(0).Points(0).Color = Drawing.Color.Red
            ElseIf aar(0) = "1" Then
                Chart1.Series(0).Points(0).Color = Drawing.Color.Yellow
            ElseIf aar(0) = "2" Then
                Chart1.Series(0).Points(0).Color = Drawing.Color.Green
            End If
```